# How to pull Instagram posts for a public account for certain account?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

How to pull Instagram posts for a public account for certain account however the account is not mine, but I need to pull its feed and its recent media.

I saw there's a way using the user_id, but how could I get the user_id from a username? OR doing it directly with the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a `GET` request to https://www.instagram.com/katyperry/?__a=1 returns a JSON packed with account information including user id, recent media, feed, etc.

`user_id = responseAsJSON.graphql.user.id`

You can replace `katyperry` with any public username.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I wanted and much more!